# Register Dll's through group policy at logon without a prompt in windows 7

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell so a step by step guide will help.
I need to run a powershell script through group policy everytime a users logs on. this is to register DLL's that regulally change.
how can i do this without a prompt coming up for the user

Answer (score 0):

What prompt are you getting? How are you running your script in the login process?

I have ran powershell scripts by using the following in a batch script

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ".\script.ps1"
```